# Random values +/- 10 from a supplied x that will not exceed a global range of 0-255

Tags: python, random, rgb, noise

I have found similar, but not suitable answers to my issue.
I need to build some noise into recieved RGB values, but the values cannot exceed 255 or be below 0.

I have the following example:

```
red,green,blue = (253, 4, 130)

print(
    (np.random.randint(red-10,red+10),
     np.random.randint(green-10,green+10),
     np.random.randint(blue-10,blue+10)))

# output values cannot be over 255 or under 0

#The following output would not be ok.
>>>(257, -2, 132)
```

How can I generate random +/- 10 value from any point within the range of 0-255 that will not exceed 255 or 0?

Comment: What do you want the rgb value when it is bigger than 255? Say, if red is 258, the value should be 255?

Comment: You've raised an excellent point I hadn't thought of.
The capping to 255 will cause a bias towards 255 selection.

So yes, if it isn't adding too much complexity - if red falls within the range of say 245-255 then regardless, the random range chosen for red should perhaps be chosen from 245-255. (Same for the minimum 0-10). 

Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You could place a conditional statement to check if the generated random number is within your required range.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np

red,green,blue = (253, 4, 130)

def rand_within_rgb(inp, thres):
    if np.random.randint(inp - thres, inp + thres) > 255:
        return 255
    elif np.random.randint(inp - thres, inp + thres) < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return np.random.randint(inp - thres, inp + thres)

print((rand_within_rgb(red, 10), 
       rand_within_rgb(green, 10), 
       rand_within_rgb(blue, 10)))
```

**Output:**

```
(253, 0, 127)
```

---

If you didn't like the clipping done above you can try changing the function to what is given below which also gives the output desired by you.

```
def rand_within_rgb(inp, thres):
    if inp + thres > 255:
        return np.random.randint(inp - thres, 255)
    elif inp - thres < 0:
        return np.random.randint(0, inp + thres)
    else:
        return np.random.randint(inp - thres, inp + thres)
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure you stay within boundaries, it would be more elegant to use `min()` and `max()` functions instead of `if/else` statements.

```py
np.random.randint(max(x-10, 0), min(x+10, 255))
```

So your code can be changed to

```py
def mutate_color(x):
    return np.random.randint(max(x-10, 0), min(x+10, 255))

red,green,blue = (253, 4, 130)

print(
    mutate_color(red),
    mutate_color(green),
    mutate_color(blue)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You either can compute the random value first and then clamp it to the desired [0, 255] range, or you can limit the random range first.

### Compute random value, then clamp

```py
def clamp(value, minValue, maxValue):
    """Returns `value` clamped to the range [minValue, maxValue]."""
    return max(minValue, min(value, maxValue))

clamp(np.random.randint(red - 10, red + 10))
```

### Limit the random range

```py
np.random.randint(max(0, red - 10), min(255, red + 10))
```

---

Note that the distribution of values will be different.  In the first version, a value that's initially 5 could be changed to a value in the range [-5, 15], which would be clipped to [0, 15].  Since all values in the range [-5, 0] would be mapped to 0, there would be greater (6 out of 21) chance of the new value being 0.

With the second approach, the random range itself is adjusted.  A value that's initially 5 would be changed to any value in the range [0, 15] with equal probability.

You will have to choose based on what you want.

Comment: Thanks for raising the excellent point about the bias towards 255,  I hadn't considered that. I've tried limiting the random range, but I'm getting an "'int' object is not callable" message. I like this idea of having a random "zone" as such on either end of the scale rather than a hard cap.

Comment: @BFG.Digital I don't know why you'd be getting an "int object is not callable" error.  Sounds like one of us made a typo with an extra set of parentheses or missing comma.  If you want to solve that, you'll need to post your code.

Comment: I solved it. It was a simple mistake on my end. Thanks James. The Limited random range solution worked perfectly.